# Click signal in Pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I have a list of buttons which is shown to the user according to a particular number which the user enters.For e.g. If the user enters 2 then only 2 buttons will be shown. 
The code that does this is here:
def set(self):
        global seismicAttributeCount,lineEditlist
        seismicAttributeCount=int(self.ui.lineEdit_23.text())
        mygroupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        myform = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        labellist = []
        buttonList= []
        for i in range(seismicAttributeCount):
            lineEditlist.append(QtGui.QLineEdit())
            buttonList.append(QtGui.QPushButton('Browse Attribute %i'%(i+1))) 
            myform.addRow(lineEditlist[i],buttonList[i])
        mygroupbox.setLayout(myform)
        self.ui.scrollArea_12.setWidget(mygroupbox)
        self.ui.scrollArea_12.setWidgetResizable(True)

```
    for i in range(seismicAttributeCount):
        if buttonList[i].clicked.connect():
            print i
```

I want to get the index of the button clicked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look into `functools.partial`. This allows you to connect an `event` with a method and a particular input. I've made here a minimal example of a GUI that does what you want

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import functools

class test(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):

        self.widget=QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Button to add buttons
        self.btnAdd = QtGui.QPushButton('Add')
        self.btnAdd.connect(self.btnAdd, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.btnAddPressed)

        # Line edit for number of buttons
        self.qleN = QtGui.QLineEdit(str(0))

        # List to keep track of buttons
        self.buttons=[]

        # Layout
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.btnAdd)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.qleN)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)   


        self.show()

    def btnAddPressed(self):

        """Adds number of buttons."""

        # Get number of buttons to add
        n=int(self.qleN.text())

        self.buttons=[]

        for i in range(n):

            # Create new button
            newBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(str(i))
            self.buttons.append(newBtn)

            # Connect
            newBtn.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.btnPressed,i))

            self.hbox.addWidget(newBtn) 

    def btnPressed(self,idx):

        """Returns idx of btn."""
        print idx
        return idx

def main():

    #Creating application   
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_win = test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note how I connect the button with a `functools` call and the index of the button.

By the way, next time, please make the effort and format your question properly.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.Thank you so much for saving me. And yes definitely, from next time I will edit my question properly